# Put bullets in a block inside itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, block

I am trying to insert bullet in a block, but these bullets appear outside this block. This is probably due to the fact that the block is inside an itemize environment. Is there a way to do it?

My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Estimation problem}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
 \begin{itemize}
\item  In finance it is a common to consider a parametric model for pricing 
derivatives and then estimate its parameters to the historical market data.
\medskip
\item  However, this practice raises some questions about its effectiveness 
and implications.
\medskip
\begin{block}{Related questions}
\medskip
\item How the best-fitting parameters' set is treated after the estimation? 
\\
\medskip
\item Does the estimation error affect financial decisions? \\
\medskip
\item How frequently does the parametric model need to be estimated?
\medskip
\end{block}
\item Our work aims to give answers to these questions and outlines an 
alternative solution
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is where the bullets appear. I would them inside the block]

Comment: On my System (Debian/TeX Live 2016) I can't reproduce your image... Missing the more important part that is the boxes in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- your mwe doesn't generate your image
- the simple way to resolve your problem is break itemize in three parts as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
%
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Estimation problem}
%\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \begin{itemize}
\item  In finance it is a common to consider a parametric model for pricing
derivatives and then estimate its parameters to the historical market data.
\item  However, this practice raises some questions about its effectiveness
and implications.
    \end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Related questions}
    \begin{itemize}
\item How the best-fitting parameters' set is treated after the estimation?
\item Does the estimation error affect financial decisions?
\item How frequently does the parametric model need to be estimated?
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}

    \begin{itemize}
\item Our work aims to give answers to these questions and outlines an
alternative solution
    \end{itemize}
%\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

from above code you can see, that i remove all `\medskip` and termination of items with `\\` (they are superfluous).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was simpler than expected. Can I ask you why `\medskip` is useless in this case? What if I would add more space between the `item` elements?.

Comment: @Alexbrini, `\itemize` is deliberately designed to give nice looking. with termination of items with `\\` and use additional vertical space like `\medskip` you will destroy this effort. this is of course is opinion based statement :)

Comment: @Alexbrini, i edit answer and give to block colors (similar to yours) as you show in your question :-)

Comment: Dear Zarko, When I add `\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont{B Yas}
\settextfont{B Yas}` before `\begin{document}` of your solution the output becomes exactly same as OP output. Is this because of `xepersian` package?

Comment: @C.F.G, sorry, I haven't any experiences with `xepersian` package, so can't give any advice for anything related to it. If you have some problem with this, I suggest you to ask new question.